# A function that collects an array of numbers as a parameter and returns an array of percentages?

Tags: javascript, loops, input

I'm currently a beginner and trying to understand how to basically use a function get an array of the numbers from each input to then figure out how to make an individual percentage for each candidate. In the JS, using that to get the total but is there a way to get each individual number from each input somehow? Maybe I'm going into a wrong direction with my for loop :/ Any direction or hints would be great.

```
<div>
<label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label>
<input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand1" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
<label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label>
<input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand2" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
<label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label>
<input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand3" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>


<output id="totalvotes"></output>
```

Here's the JS for it

```
function totalVotes() {
  var votes = document.getElementsByName("votesPerPerson");
  var totalVotes = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < votes.length; i ++ ) {
  totalVotes += parseInt(votes[i].value);
}
 document.getElementById("totalvotes").innerHTML = totalVotes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a good grasp of getting the sum. To create an array, there's several ways you can do that but I recommend mapping it from the collection of elements like this:

```js
function totalVotes() {
  var votes = document.getElementsByName("votesPerPerson");
  var total = document.getElementById("totalvotes");
  // create new array
  var percentages = [];
  var totalVotes = 0;

  // reset innerHTML in case loop returns early due to invalid value
  total.innerHTML = "";
  
  // reset each vote percentage
  for (var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
    votes[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "";
  }

  // overwrite each index with value
  for (var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
    totalVotes += percentages[i] = parseInt(votes[i].value);
    
    // one of the values is invalid
    if (isNaN(percentages[i])) return;
  }

  total.innerHTML = totalVotes;

  // calculate percentages here by mapping array of votes
  for (var i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
    percentages[i] = 100 * percentages[i] / totalVotes;
    
    votes[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = percentages[i].toFixed(2) + "%";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('change', totalVotes)
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand1" placeholder="Vote count">
  <output></output>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand2" placeholder="Vote count">
  <output></output>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand3" placeholder="Vote count">
  <output></output>
</div>

<output id="totalvotes"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function totalVotes() {
  var votes = document.getElementsByName("votesPerPerson");
  var totalVotes = 0;
  var percentages = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < votes.length; i ++ ) {
    totalVotes += parseInt(votes[i].value);
    percentages[i] = parseInt(votes[i].value);
  }
  percentages = percentages.map(function(candidateVotes) {return candidateVotes/totalVotes;});
  document.getElementById("totalvotes").innerHTML = totalVotes;
}
```

The percentages are in the array of the same name, then you can do whatever you want with it!
Hopes this helps!

Comment: I'm going to talk myself through this so I can understand what you did. So you made a variable called percentages assigned it to an empty array. Then used the for loop meaning each vote input like index[0] for the first candidate = percentage[0]? Then closed the loop. Could you explain the next line? Sorry, still learning the language.

Comment: As you noticed, I use your loop to store each candidate's vote in an array. The map function is very interesting, because it 'auto' iterates on the array and for each item, it returns the result of the function I pass in parameter (which computes the percentage). This maps an array to another array, which contains each candidate percentage! Some documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: Is there some way of taking each input from the array and put each voting percentage to each candidate in a div? I am really clueless :( I put in the JS fiddle to show. https://jsfiddle.net/rtomino/p24zhwgu/

Comment: @BeckyT see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44829666/1541563) for how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You mostly have the idea. You just need to attach some event handlers (with one other minor change).

```js
function totalVotes() {
  var votes = document.getElementsByName("votesPerPerson");
  var totalVotes = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
    totalVotes += parseInt(votes[i].value || 0); // "Minor change" here
  }
  document.getElementById("totalvotes").innerHTML = totalVotes;
}

// Additions below this point
var votes = document.getElementsByName("votesPerPerson");
for( var i = 0; i < votes.length; i ++ ) {
  votes[i].addEventListener('change', totalVotes);
}

totalVotes(); // Run once to get 0 to show without changing anything
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand1" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand2" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand3" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>


<output id="totalvotes"></output>
```

Now, that code works, but note some of the repetition, global variables, etc. Here's an alternative that may offer you some different ways of accomplishing the same things:

```js
// If you want to know what this outer function is, look up "IIFE"
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // Get the elements (and make sure they are put in an array)
  var voteInputEls = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByName('votesPerPerson')
  );

  // This is used below to handle the change event
  function setTotalVotes() {

    // "reduce" the voteInputEls array to a total value
    var totalVotes = voteInputEls.reduce(function (lastVal, voteInputEl) {
      return lastVal + parseInt(voteInputEl.value || 0);
    }, 0);

    document.getElementById('totalvotes').innerHTML = totalVotes;
  }

  // Attach event listeners
  voteInputEls.forEach(function(voteInputEl) {
    voteInputEl.addEventListener('change', setTotalVotes);
  });
  setTotalVotes(); // Run once to get 0

})();
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="votes1">Votes for Candidate 1</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand1" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes2">Votes for Candidate 2</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand2" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="votes3">Votes for Candidate 3</label>
  <input type="number" name="votesPerPerson" id="cand3" placeholder="Vote count">
</div>


<output id="totalvotes"></output>
```